# Fix Height of JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, jtextarea

I'm still inexperienced with creating Java GUIs, and I'm having trouble with the JTextArea. I would like to fix it's height (number of columns) but it seems to always fill the available space. I've read on the Internet that you should place it inside a JScrollPane, which I've done, but the same thing happens.

This is some example code:

```
public class TestWindow extends JFrame {

    public TestWindow() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(5, 10)));

        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

With this code, the JTextArea fills the whole window. Any way I can fix it to a specific number of rows and columns? Could it have something to do with the layout manager?

Comment: Don't you mean the number of `rows` to fix it's height? The number of `columns` only affects its width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default layout is BorderLayout which expands all the content to fit the whole area, you have to set a new Layout, I recommend GridBagLayout to extensive control of the sizes, or which I most use, BoxLayout

Comment: Thanks. I'm using GroupLayout for my actual program. Does it have the same effect as BorderLayout? Should I change to another layout?

Answer (score 2):

You could add the component in the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` location which respects the height of preferred sizes

```
add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(5, 10)), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Comment: @mKorbel Yes well you would obviously need something in CENTER location - assuming that this is an unfinished UI

Answer (score 0):

In this case (without another layoutmanager), telling the number of columns won't control the component's height. You would need to manually set the size of it, using setSize().

Comment: *"telling the number of columns won't control the component's height"* It will if added with a `PAGE_START` or `PAGE_END` constraint.